# Как воспользоваться ООП?

Tags: php, mysql, ооп, функции, pdo

Пишу не большой Product List с функциями CRUD. Реализовал это всё в процедурном стиле, сейчас переделываю на ООП вариант, и немножко подвис вопрос в голове, как ООП работает. Создал классы под каждый продукт их три штуки, в каждом классе описывается CRUD метод для своего продукта. Сделал общий родительский класс Product, туда добавил общие переменные для всех продуктов и унаследовал их. Создал ProductInterface, куда поместил контракты метод этих продуктов и родительский класс `Product implements productInterface`, соответственно, классы-продукты получает эти методы, в IDE появились эти стрелки сбоку. Подскажите, как мне воспользоваться ООП дальше, чтобы увидеть его в действии.

Родительский класс Product.php

```
require_once 'Interface/ProductInterface.php';
class Product implements productInterface {

private $conn;
private $table_name = "Books";

public $id;
public $sku;
public $img;
public $name;
public $description;
public $price;

public function __construct($db){
    $this->conn = $db;
}
public function readAll(){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM " . $this->table_name . " ORDER BY id DESC";
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare( $query );
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt;
}
```

Интерфейс ProductInterface.php

```
interface productInterface
{
public function readAll();

public function readOne();

public function create();

public function delete();

}
```

И сам класс продукт допустим Books

```
require_once 'Product.php';

class books extends Product  {

public $author;
public $weight;
// object properties

public function readAll(){

}
    //query to read one book and all data of it by `id` from `book` table
function readOne(){
    $query = "SELECT sku, name, img, author, price, weight, description FROM " . $this->table_name . "
        WHERE id = ? LIMIT 0,1";

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare( $query );
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $this->id);
    $stmt->execute();

    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    //data that will be executed in `book_id`
    $this->sku = $row['sku'];
    $this->name = $row['name'];
    $this->img = $row['img'];
    $this->author = $row['author'];
    $this->description = $row['description'];
    $this->weight = $row['weight'];
    $this->price = $row['price'];
}

// query to create new book
function create(){
    //query for creating new book in table
    $query = "INSERT INTO " . $this->table_name . " (sku, name, author, description, price, weight)" .
        "VALUES ('{$this->sku}','{$this->name}','{$this->author}','{$this->description}','{$this->price}','{$this->weight}');";

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

    // posted values
    $this->sku=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->sku));
    $this->name=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->name));
    $this->author=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->author));
    $this->description=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->description));
    $this->price=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->price));
    $this->weight=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->weight));

    // bind values
    $stmt->bindParam(":sku", $this->sku);
    $stmt->bindParam(":name", $this->name);
    $stmt->bindParam(":author", $this->author);
    $stmt->bindParam(":description", $this->description);
    $stmt->bindParam(":price", $this->price);
    $stmt->bindParam(":weight", $this->weight);

    if($stmt->execute()){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
// query for updating book and change book data in simple form
function update(){
    $query = "UPDATE
            " . $this->table_name . "
        SET
            sku = :sku,
            name = :name,
            author = :author,
            price = :price,
            weight = :weight,
            description = :description
        WHERE
            id = :id";

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

    // posted values that user can change
    $this->sku=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->sku));
    $this->name=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->name));
    $this->author=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->author));
    $this->weight=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->weight));
    $this->price=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->price));
    $this->description=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->description));
    $this->id=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->id));

    // bind parameters
    $stmt->bindParam(':sku', $this->sku);
    $stmt->bindParam(':author', $this->author);
    $stmt->bindParam(':name', $this->name);
    $stmt->bindParam(':price', $this->price);
    $stmt->bindParam(':weight', $this->weight);
    $stmt->bindParam(':description', $this->description);
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $this->id);

    // execute the query
    if($stmt->execute()){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

//query to delete the product by id
function delete(){
    $query = "DELETE FROM " . $this->table_name . " WHERE id = ?";

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $this->id);

    if($result = $stmt->execute()){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

Может как-то можно наследовать эти методы что бы в каждом классе их не писать, методы readAll и delete вообще не отличаются кроме как таблица другая в базе.

Код реализацие метода readAll.

```
<?php
    // read the books from the database
    $books = new Books($db);
    $stmt = $books->readAll();
    while ($books = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        extract($books);
        echo "<div data-price='{$price}' class='item'>";
        echo "<a href='book_id.php?id={$id}'><img class='product' src='UI/images/{$img}'></a> ";
        echo "<div class='info'>";
        echo "<h6 align='center'> <a href='book_id.php?id={$id}'></a>{$name}</h6> ";
        echo "<p class='descroption'>ID number: {$id} </p>";
        echo "<p class='descroption'>SKU number: {$sku} </p>";
        echo "<p class='descroption'>Price: {$price} <i class='glyphicon-euro'></i></p>";
        echo "<p class='descroption'>Weight: {$weight}  kg</p>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";
    }
    ?>
```

Жду от вас конструктивной критики и советов.

Comment: зачем коннекшен выносить в конечные классы? это должно быть уровне `Product` как и `table_name`, так что в целом весь `readAll` метод можно реализовать на уровне родительского класса. Дочерние лишь должны перекрыть значение этой переменной. Обработка входящих данных тоже должна быть в другом месте. и еще про переменные переменных почитайте. кучу строк можно сократить до простого цикла с именами

Comment: еще про шаблонизаторы почитайте: smarty, twig и т.п. а фетч делайте в самих методах, зачем этим заниматься в вызывающем коде? да и вообще удобнее будет если будут отдельные классы сущностей, и отдельный класс репозитория для чтения

Comment: @teran изменил в родительском классе и в дочернем, метод добавил в родительский, как наследовать этот метод и реализовать его?

Comment: `tableName` сделайте `protected` и укажите его значение в конструкторе books. а `readAll` из books удалите вовсе, тогда он и будет унаследован, а не перекрыт.

Comment: @teran спасибо как вы сказали получилось! а как реализовать если у меня не сколько таблиц а методы одинаковы, но в каждом а параметры а каждого продукта отличаются. Например в книгах есть weight a dvd capacity. я эти параметры добавил в класс продукт, а из родительского он наследует всё остальное. И извините ещё  за один глупый вопрос, но какую роль во всё играет интерфейс со своими контрактами?

Comment: поля вам _возможно_ следует в какой нить массив `$properties = ['sku' => null , 'name' => null]` вынести. таким образом в базовом классе определить общие свойства, а в дочернем добавить новые. +реализовать `__get/__set` методы (в базовом) для доступа к ним. Что касается интерфейсов то для данной задачи они и не нужны.